# Unknown host google.com despite interface DNS entry

Tags: networking, server, dns

I have a Ubuntu machine that has access to the internet but fails to resolve hostnames.

I tried to edit `/etc/resolv.conf` like suggested in various places. But I can't display its contents or edit it permanently.

### The interface config

My Network config at `/etc/network/interfaces` looks like so:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your
# system and how to activate them. For more information, see
# interfaces(5).

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 46.101.158.60
        netmask 255.255.192.0
        gateway 46.101.128.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

### Nameservers

So I do have a dns record and it points to `8.8.8.8` and `8.8.4.4` respectively.

I can ping these two:

```
# ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=124 time=0.965 ms
64 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=124 time=0.538 ms

# ping 8.8.4.4
PING 8.8.4.4 (8.8.4.4) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 8.8.4.4: icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=0.977 ms
```

### Details

```
$ uname -a
Linux XYXY 3.13.0-57-generic #95-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 19 09:28:15 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Resolv.conf

The file is there in `/etc`.

```
# ls -lia /etc/resolv.conf 
655492 lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 29 Jul  5 15:29 /etc/resolv.conf -> ../run/resolvconf/resolv.conf
```

However I can't show the contents of it.

```
# cat /etc/resolv.conf 
cat: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

Additionally I can't change the file:

```
# echo "nameserver 8.8.8.8" >  /etc/resolv.conf
-bash: /etc/resolv.conf: No such file or directory
```

### Workaround

As an initial workaround I did add some hosts in `/etc/hosts` but this gets very tedious once I need more domains.

<sub>Internal Reference VS#284</sub>

Comment: Does your actual `/etc/resolv.conf` correspond to the entry in `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: best safe solution is to reboot the computer (@Jos probably not, he said "the file gets deleted automatically")

Comment: I've never heard of `/etc/resolv.conf` not being present at any Linux system - it will be regenerated, but never completely removed. @Besi did you restart the `networking` service?

Comment: I did reboot the machine. I did update the question regarding `resolv.conf`

Comment: @Jos I can neither display nor edit the file (as root). See my updated question.

Comment: Your `ls -lia` command gives the same result on my system; however, I can `cat` the file, even as a common user. My file `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` has permissions `-rw-r--r--`.

Comment: @Jos Thank you for your help. I having a file in either `var` or `run` did not work for me and those files got purged upon reboot. So I did move the file to my home folder. Thanks for your help. You may add an answer which I will upvote / accept.

Answer (score 0):

I did resolve the issue by sym-linking the `/etc/resolv.conf` file with a file in my home folder:

```
ln -s /home/me/config/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

And then adding the nameservers there:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea: the link will be overwritten by the next update of `resolvconf`.